# How to determine if JSON is object or array in cpp, and if object convert it to array?

Tags: c++, arrays, json, json-api

I was searching for that, but found answers regarding java.

For a long time, I was receiving JSON responses as array, even when I had one response only.
Example:

```
  {"intervention":

    [
     { 
      "id":"3",
              "subject":"dddd",
              "details":"dddd",
              "beginDate":"2012-03-08T00:00:00+01:00",
              "endDate":"2012-03-18T00:00:00+01:00",
              "campus":
                       { 
                         "id":"2",
                         "name":"paris"
                       }
           }
     ]
}
```

now I can recive it either as an array, or as an object. meaning these `[ , ]` are no longer appear. 
As you may guess, my code crushes as I'm using it as array..

I want to do something like that:

```
if (parsedJson["intervention"] == jsonObject])
   covertObjectToArray
```

I've tried (pseudo) :

```
std::string tmp = parsedJson["intervention"].asString()
if (firstChar is "{")
{
   concat : "[ + tmp + ] ";
   parseStringBackToJSon
}
```

but it crashed!

can you please help?

Comment: Do you use your own parsing or boost::property_tree::json_parser::* ?

Comment: i'm not using boost for now. But I am using json parser (json reader - that converts string to json)

Comment: So you are writing your own parser?

Comment: oh no, it is a json stantart library. I hope im not mistaken with that http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html

Comment: I am not familiar with that library, but it does seem to provide `isArray` and `isObject` functions.  You might explore those.

Comment: yeah Im tryin it now, but there is nothing to convert object to array :(

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right from your initial question and the comments you would like to transform an element in the JSon tree if it is a simple object into an array containing that object. I'm also not familiar with that lib but for me it would be something like.

```
Value & v = parseJSon["intervention"];
if(v.isObject()) {
 Value vcopy = v;
 v.clear();
 v.append(vcopy);
}
```

Just fantasy code based on the API doc.